# How To show button when button is clicked on ionic3

Tags: html, css, ionic3

In My Project

I have a Two Buttons

1.`click here` button

2.`save` button

First i need to display only `click here` button, when user click `click here` button then `save` button will need to display on ionic3

Comment: check it i already solve this......

Comment: yes, its working well.thanks

Comment: ok give me accept tik mark @vignesh

Comment: tnx for supporting me

Comment: Hi if there is any chance,that when click the `click here` button, i need to display a popup with label feild along with `save button` @Utpaul

Comment: clarify it .... with new post...

Comment: ok i will do @Utpaul

Comment: ok that's great @vignesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In .ts file declare variable `showFlag`**

```
showFlag:boolean=false;
```

**And also create a function for show save button**

```
  showSaveButton(){
    this.showFlag=true;
  }
```

**In `.html`**

```
  <button ion-button (click)="showSaveButton()">click here</button>
  <button ion-button *ngIf="showFlag">save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember a boolean in your ts file

```
isButtonClicked: boolean = false
```

Change this boolean to true when the "click here" button is clicked and in the save button use ngif

```
<button *ngIf="isButtonClicked"> Save me </button>
```

Now the button wil show when the boolean is true and hide when it is false